# Header and Footer link to multiple web pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to separate a header and footer of my webpage from the index page. I found a javascript code and html tag for this:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("[data-load]").each(function(){
        $(this).load($(this).data("load"), function(){
        });
    });
})
</script>
<nav data-load="header.php"></nav>
```

It worked out. It displayed the header in the index page. However I just noticed that when I am trying to hover the menu in the index page, the submenu can no longer display. while in header page there seems to be no problem. It displays the menus properly.
I can still see the submenus in header page whenever i hover the mouse. Nonetheless I can no longer do this on index page.

I am thinking maybe there's a conflict between my javascript code with the code I used to link the header in index page.

Please help me figure out what's wrong and what would be the possible code for this in order for it to display the menu properly.

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you forgot to load the stylesheet?

Comment: I have included it sir.

Comment: Build your header and footer  html code in javascript and append that DOM where you want to place header and footer from same javascript function to each your page.

Comment: see console on your browser, you may see maybe a 404 of some js

Answer (score 0):

you can use php header function rather than using javascript

Comment: I am trying to use php and been searching for possible codes but it didn't worked out.
Thank for your suggestion though

Comment: use this header("Location: header.php")